# How to append data into table without using id?

Tags: javascript, html

So here's my code:

The table, this holds details of the candidates:

```
<table id="candidates-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Candidate Picture</th>
      <th scope="col">Candidate Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Contestant ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Elections</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="candidates-table-body">
    <!--Here data comes from data.js file-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

data.js code:

Assume that the function is being called and the complete code is executed without errors:

```
function refreshCandidateTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'load_candidates_details.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      document.getElementById("candidates-table-body").innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("candidates-table-body").innerHTML += "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + res[i].contestant_picture + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + res[i].contestant_name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + res[i].contestant_id + "</td>" +
          "<td'>" + res[i].election_type + "</td>" +
          "<td><a href='#new-candidate' onclick='changeCandidateDetails()' style='padding-right: 1rem' id='edit-candidate'>Edit</a>" +
          "<a href='#new-candidate' id='remove-candidate'>Remove</a></td></tr>";
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Until here everything works fine.

When I click the 'Edit' link in the "Action" column a card pops up which is as follows:

```
<div class="row card mb-5" id="change-candidate-details" style="display: none; padding-top: 1rem">
  <div class="card-header">
    Edit candidate details
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form id="edit-candidate-candidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add_candidate.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Candidate Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="candidate-name" placeholder="Enter candidate name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Election Type</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg" id="candidate-election-type" required>
                                <option disabled>Select the Election Type</option>
                                <option name="SVC">School Vice Captain</option>
                                <option name="SHB">School Head Boy</option>
                                <option name="BHC">Bhaskara House Captain</option>
                                <option name="BVC">Bhaskara House Vice Captain</option>
                                <option name="SHC">Shushrutha House Captain</option>
                                <option name="SHVC">Shushrutha House Vice Captain</option>
                                <option name="CHC">Charaka House Captain</option>
                                <option name="CVC">Charaka House Vice Captain</option>
                            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file input-lg" id="candidate-picture" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control input-lg" id="submit-candidate-details">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="change-candidate-form-response" style="display: none; padding-top: 2rem">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in this card I want the details of the candidate to be present; for example in the table there is a row as follows:

```
candidatepicture.jpg Goutam RVPS2018GOUSBC SBC Change Remove
```

When I click change on the above row I need the details to be added to card. i.e the input fields should show a default value equivalent to the row where the change link was clicked.

I have no idea how do achieve it since `document.getElementById()` cannot be used as I have not assigned any id's to it. The problem is I'm not able to figure out a way to find out which row in the table was clicked.

Even if I find out which row was clicked I do not have any idea of how to proceed further as I'm fairly new to JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to:

- 1) keep the ajax data in a traversable collection when you receive it
- 2) find a way to map each row to each element of your data collection
- 3) use this mapping when handling the click on "edit"

**Define a variable with same scope as refreshCandidateTable and changeCandidateDetails to store the data from the response**

```
// this variable will be visible in both refreshCandidateTable and changeCandidateDetails
var candidatesData = {};
function refreshCandidateTable() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'load_candidates_details.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        document.getElementById("candidates-table-body").innerHTML = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            // we will be able to get the contestant object by writing candidatesData[id], we just need a way to pass this id
            candidates[res[i].contestant_id] = res[i];
            document.getElementById("candidates-table-body").innerHTML += "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + res[i].contestant_picture + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + res[i].contestant_name + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + res[i].contestant_id + "</td>" +
                "<td'>" + res[i].election_type + "</td>" +
                "<td><a href='#new-candidate' onclick='changeCandidateDetails("+res[i].contestant_id+")' style='padding-right: 1rem' id='edit-candidate'>Edit</a>" +
                "<a href='#new-candidate' id='remove-candidate'>Remove</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
})
```

}

The id is passed in the handler `onclick='changeCandidateDetails("+res[i].contestant_id+")'`
Now the changeCadidateDetails will be called with the proper id as parameter.

so in changeCandidateDetails:

```
function changeCandidateDetails(id) {
    var candidate = candidatesData[id];
    .... // show your form an update the fields with the values from candidate
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing the id we can pass the index and then access any details we want...I guess that would be more appropriate

Comment: It depends if you plan on reordering the rows without having to reorder the mapping.... Most of the time, relying on the ui presentation is bad

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the td in the onclick event like that

```
onclick='changeCandidateDetails(this)'
```

Inside your method get whole row with $(this).parent() and you will have the whole data from that tr and you can process it

Comment: if $(this).parent() is used i will get all td's ...then how would i seperate them?? I'm not using id attribute

Comment: Calling `$(this).parent()` on clicking anchor tag will return you it's immediate parent `tr` not all of them.